# Asking a non-code based question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question for isn't technically code based however could eventually branch in to code examples, its not really an opinion based question as such as I assume there is an almost "standard best practice" style answer however in my research around the question I keep finding multiple conflicting answers and would appreciate some direct input from some other knowledgable devs.

I've tried on forums but the question is sufficiently complex that it is well beyond what most forum members are capable of having input on however I know there are a few on here who would most certainly have some input that I could find useful.

I'm not asking (really don't want them to) write the code for me its more of suggestions on what/how to approach it and what pitfalls to avoid etc to keep the system optimised and fast while performing a complex task.

Is there a place anywhere on SO that would be suitable for a question like this?  (if needs be I can actually post the question here and you can judge just let me know)

Edited in brief idea of question without going whole hog on details.

> 2 Database column firstname, surname in an innodb table so no option
>   to use match(). Single unified search box allowing search of either or
>   both columns. So if the table has a row with FN = David and SN =
>   Hinchliffe Using simple wildcard searches works fine if you just
>   search for FN or SN however if you put "David Hinchliffe" in to the
>   search box you end up with '%David Hinchliffe%' which obviously won't
>   match either.  Without splitting on spaces and writing sql / case
>   statement hell how do you search both fields effectively the same as
>   doing `FN LIKE '%dav%' OR FN LIKE '%hin%' OR SN LIKE '%dav%' OR SN
>   LIKE '%hin%'`

Hopefully that gives you enough of an idea of the issue without me going in to mad detail (there's more than 2 fields in the real instance for example)

Comment: Sounds unlikely this would make a good question from what you've written. Closure as either primarily opinion based or too broad would be the most likely outcome for it.

Comment: That was my thought which is why I asked here first :) problem is I can't really find anywhere with the level/quality developers this place has to pick their brains :(  I feel its almost like just asking for a "chat" but the chat isn't really the place either as it could get technical enough that there is a benefit to others in future.

Comment: It might be easier to discuss if you actually included the question you're thinking of asking. That said, *"what/how to approach it and what pitfalls to avoid"* certainly sounds too broad for SO.

Comment: Have added in an example of the question or at least a simplified version.

Comment: @Dave The preliminary question you edited in sounds like, at least as far as scope and breadth are concerned, an entirely normal Stack Overflow question. I suspect it wouldn't work well at Software Engineering. Bill suggested that presumably because he thought, like I did, that you wanted to ask a design question.

Comment: This is where I wasn't sure though as tbh it could go the way of designing search algorithms ie: google style.  Or it could go the other route of just plugging in a 3rd party full text search style ie: lucene.  I can't seem to find anything to match it or even similar on SE. SO is what put me on to lucene but I'm not convinced, so was hoping to attract input from people who had written stuff like this before. Previous experience of asking complex questions on SO has left them unanswered, it seems there's lots of "easy" questions people can answer but not so much when they get more complex.

Comment: It could of course also be a more generic design issue should I add a 3rd field in for example that is FN/SN combined and just stick with the wildcards against that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977386/search-multiple-database-columns-using-one-search-box and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211813/searching-multiple-columns-with-one-or-more-keywords-using-sql looked interesting especially as i'd forgot about mysql regex as an option but that also seems slow after a quick benchmark.

Comment: Required reading: [Best practice zombies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228)

Comment: I think that it is a fair question here provided that you actually make it answerable. Just call it what it is, search. Many places, including Stack Overflow, struggle or fail with implementing search, and the leading author of a search algorithm is one of the richest people on the planet. So long as you can outline what you are doing and what went wrong with your search approach - this can include time or space complexity - then it should be on topic. Keep in mind though, Google's search algorithms, and many search algorithms, are proprietary and as such may limit answerers.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like a question that might be suitable for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). You can review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to see if your question fits their guidelines. I also find it helpful to look around to see how similar questions are received before I post a question on a new site.

Comment: Think i'd discounted that section before as most people would laugh if I said "php" and "software engineering" in the same sentance :)  Just reading though now see if I can find something similar to make sure it is the right place before I go spamming it up with a question :)

Comment: Interesting enough "Your search returned no matches." when searching for similar things on SE but SO pointed me to lucene and solr which may actually help me in a round about kinda way.

Answer (score 4):

> its not really an opinion based question as such as I assume there is an almost "standard best practice" style answer

A reference to some "best practice" would make your question opinion-based by definition, as any of us might then ask "Best practice according to whom?" The good news is that "best practice" is, for the purposes of Stack Overflow, a content-free expression, and so you should be able to formulate your question without any reference to a supposed "best practice". Work out your problem until it can be stated in terms of concrete requirements which are verifiable independently of the opinion of anyone.

> I'm not asking (really don't want them to) write the code for me its more of suggestions on what/how to approach it and what pitfalls to avoid etc to keep the system optimised and fast while performing a complex task.

That might easily lead to a question that is unanswerable for being too broad, specially because it does not sound like a conceptual question that might lend itself to a bird's eye, very high level summarising answer by an expert. If you read your question and sense that a satisfactory answer would require, for instance, a book chapter or a full proof-of-concept implementation, break down your problem in several separate questions that are a better fit for the relatively concise format of Stack Overflow Q&A.

Comment: I have a feeling someone with a suitable knowledge/prior experience level would just go "you do it like this xyz" :) I'm just looking at software engineering section suggested by bill below. See if it'll fit there.

Comment: @Dave Yup, it sounds like a more natural fit might be possible at that site.